# Trying to refresh one div content on a page without changing position of the div

Tags: ajax, html, position, refresh, css-float

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

        <title>ajax div example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dbn,machine_name;
function main_draw(d,m,r)
{
    dbn = d;
    machine_name = m;
    draw_charts();
    if ( r > 0 )
        {
            setRefreshid = setInterval("draw_pie()",r);
        }
}
function draw_charts()
{

document.getElementById('ajdiv4').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('ajdiv3').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('ajdiv2').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('ajdiv1').innerHTML = "";
draw_pie();
draw_line();
draw_space();
draw_backup();

}

function draw_pie()
{
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax( {

        url: 'JSCharts/graph_pie1.html',
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#ajdiv4").html(html);
        }
    }); }, 100);
}

function draw_line()
{
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax( {

        url: 'JSCharts/graph_line1.html',
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#ajdiv3").html(html);
        }
    });  }, 200);
}

function draw_space()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax( {

        url: 'JSCharts/space_graph.php',
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#ajdiv2").html(html);
        }
    });  }, 300);
}

function draw_backup()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax( {

        url: 'JSCharts/backup_graph.php',
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#ajdiv1").html(html);
        }
    });  }, 400);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="ajdiv1" style="float:left"></div>
<div id="ajdiv2" style="float:left"></div>
<div id="ajdiv3" style="float:left"></div>
<div id="ajdiv4" style="float:left"></div>

<button id="b1" onclick="main_draw('CQ1','va2apsap010',10000)">Display Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is an entire code which makes AJAX calls upon clicking on "Display Content" and after that it refreshes content of div "ajdiv4" by calling function "draw_pie". The only problem with this is that when it refreshes, it moves the pie graph all the way to the left. I would like it to stay and update it in the current position. Please help if any of you know what is going on here, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the dimensions of your DIVs? With your current code, you could probably do:

```
<style>
#ajdiv1, #ajdiv2, #ajdiv3, #ajdiv4 {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
} 
</style>
```

Alternatively, add a class attribute to simplify things:

```
<style>
.chartContainer {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
} 
</style>
```

If you have a working version up, or can post something on JSfiddle, that would make things easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks Anders for a quick reply. I am new to this site so I am not sure if I can send an attachment here which may be more helpful. Basically what is happening is that it display four graphs from left to right with (float left ) the first time. After 10 seconds it tries to refresh div "ajdiv4" by ajax call to "draw_pie()" function but this time it moves from the rightmost position in the screen to the leftmost and overwrites another graph. I would like it to stay in the same original position and display the new content. I have not specified height,width since I want to let it float as is.

Comment: Anders, I have not played with jsfiddle but I can send entire set of files to have working code which includes several PHP files and HTML.